# Why does not lag increase when exception occurs in Spring Kafka Consumer

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, autocommit

I'm using a spring kafka and I have a question.
The Spring Kafka version is 2.6.X.

I set the auto commit setting to false.
At this time, the consumer who consumes the message forced an error.
As I expected, the commit was not done manually, so the lag should be increased.
However, lag did not increase.
What do you do with an existing default error handler?

```
class KafkaConsumerConfig {
  @Bean
    fun multiTypeConsumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String, Any> {
        val props = HashMap<String, Any>()
        props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9092"
        props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = JsonDeserializer::class.java
        props[ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG] = false
        return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props)
    }

    @Bean
    fun multiTypeKafkaListenerContainerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Any> {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Any>()
        factory.setConsumerFactory(multiTypeConsumerFactory())
        return factory
    }



}

@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = ["testTopic"], groupId = "group_sdas")
class Consumer {

    @KafkaHandler
    fun handleFoo(message: Foo) {
        println("Received Message in group foo: ${message}")
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    fun handleBar(message: Bar) {
        throw RuntimeException("ssstest sss")
    }


    

}
```

The lag does not increase even if an error occurs because the **type id** is not included in the header.

Comment: Set your AckMode to MANUAL and add a parameter to commit (or not) `fun handleBar(message: Bar, ack: Acknowledgment) { ... ack.acknowledge(); }`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/#committing-offsets

Comment: If the auto commit is set to false, shouldn't we make a manual commit regardless of the access mode?  And even if ackMode is MANUAL
There is no typeid header, so org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class, but it is committed in the error handler, so the lag does not seem to increase.

Comment: If you can get deserialization exceptions, you need to use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer